# How to increase variables by 1 in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I would like to know how to increase variables in Nim by 1, alike the `(variablename)++` function in other programming languages.

My Code by far:

```py
int i = 1
int j = 1
for i in countup(1, 10):
  j = j + 1
  echo "number: "
  echo i
```

I want to change the `j = j + 1` with the Nim version of: `j++`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the += operator:

```
j += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can increment a variable by one in Nim with the `inc()` function: `inc(var_name)`

Comment: And unlike Pascal, Nim can implement the `inc()` function without parenths. Such as: `inc j`